# Can you call an MVC action within a webform aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

Is it possible to call MVC controller/actions from a webforms page?

So heres a webform page:

```
<html>
<body>
<asp:label runat="server" id="lbl1">Hi, I'm a label.</asp:Label>

<%=Html.Action("Controller","Action")%>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forked and created MvcInteropX to help with integrating MVC into an existing webforms app

Check it out: [www.nuget.org/packages/MvcInteropX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcInteropX)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [HTML helper available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), then do it the way you're trying to:

```
Html.Action("Controller","Action");
```

Otherwise, just use a plain link:

```
<a href="www.domain.com/controller/action/params">Link</a>
```

Setting the controller and action name, and optionally the params. MVC controllers response to plain HTTP request so this will work. Now, remember that *www.domain.com/controller/action/params* works when using default [MVC default routing mechanism](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx). If your MVC implementation use a different one, then you'll need to change the address appropriately.

Comment: I need that action (should mention that it would return a partial view) to actually execute in-place.